# How to calculate the mean value of the column inside the function

Tags: r, statistics

I want to calculate the mean value of the column inside the function. Let's try in this example:

```
test = data.frame(value = c(231,43,12,342,123,543,56,122,321,222),
              category = c("A","B","A","B","A","A","A","B","B","B"))


  fun <- function(AorB) {
  example <- test %>% 
   filter(category == AorB) %>%
   select(value) 
   ## %>%           (here I want to add mean calculation)
   ## mean()        (it is not possible)
   ## sum()/nrow    (it is not possible)
  }

  solve <- fun("A")
```

The whole problem with 'mean()' and 'sum()/nrow()' is that the 'mean()' and 'nrow()' need to specify the data.frame. All calculations are inside the function so I can't specify the data.frame like this:

```
mean(example$value)
```

Comment: I think you need to use `example <- test %>% filter(category == AorB) %>% summarise( mean = mean(value)`

Comment: Yes, exactly, it works! Thank You very much. I'm new here and I don't know how can I give you the thumb up when you add just a comment?

Comment: I reposted it as an answer if you'd like to give me credit for it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per Sin's suggestion in the comments...

I think you need to use:

```
example <- test %>% filter(category == AorB) %>% summarise( mean = mean(value))
```

For dplyr, you need to call (and name) those summary functions within the summarise() function.